# Mongoose: consistently save document order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose we have a schema like this:

```
const PageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: String
  order: Number
})
```

We want `order` to be always a unique number between `0` and `n-1`, where `n` is the total number of documents.

How can we ensure this when documents are inserted or deleted?

For inserts I currently use this hook:

```js
PageSchema.pre('save', async function () {
  if (!this.order) {
    const lastPage = await this.constructor.findOne().sort({ order: -1 })
    this.order = lastPage ? lastPage.order + 1 : 0
  }
})
```

This seems to work when new documents are inserted.
When documents are removed, I would have to decrease the `order` of documents of higher `order`. However, I am not sure which hooks are called when documents are removed.

Efficiency is not an issue for me: there are not many inserts and deletes.
It would be totally ok if I could somehow just provide one function, say `fix_order`, that iterates over the whole collection. How can I install this function such that it gets called whenever documents are inserted or deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findOneAndDelete pre and post hooks to accomplish this.

As you see in the pre findOneAndDelete hook, we save a reference to the deleted document, and pass it to the postfindOneAndDelete, so that we can access the model using constructor, and use the updateMany method to be able to adjust orders.

```js
PageSchema.pre("findOneAndDelete", async function(next) {
  this.page = await this.findOne();
  next();
});

PageSchema.post("findOneAndDelete", async function(doc, next) {
  console.log(doc);

  const result = await this.page.constructor.updateMany(
    { order: { $gt: doc.order } },
    {
      $inc: {
        order: -1
      }
    }
  );

  console.log(result);

  next();
});
```

Let's say you have these 3 documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e830a6d0dec1443e82ad281"),
        "content": "content1",
        "order": 0,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e830a6d0dec1443e82ad282"),
        "content": "content2",
        "order": 1,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e830a6d0dec1443e82ad283"),
        "content": "content3",
        "order": 2,
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

When you delete the content2 with `"_id": ObjectId("5e830a6d0dec1443e82ad282")` with findOneAndDelete method like this:

```js
router.delete("/pages/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Page.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
  res.send(result);
});
```

The middlewares will run, and adjust the orders, the remaining 2 documents will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e830a6d0dec1443e82ad281"),
        "content": "content1",
        "order": 0,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e830a6d0dec1443e82ad283"),
        "content": "content3",
        "order": 1,    => DECREASED FROM 2 to 1
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Also you had better to include next in your pre save middleware so that other middlewares also work if you add later.

```js
PageSchema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  if (!this.order) {
    const lastPage = await this.constructor.findOne().sort({ order: -1 });
    this.order = lastPage ? lastPage.order + 1 : 0;
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: That works. Thank you so much! Only one thing I changed: I think we do not need the pre findOneAndDelete hook, as we can access the model in the post hook from `this`:

```PageSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function (doc, next) {
  await this.model.updateMany(
    { order: { $gt: doc.order } },
    { $inc: { order: -1 } }
  )
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of SuleymanSah, I wrote a mongoose plugin that does the job. This way, it can be applied to multiple schemas without unnessecary code duplication.

It has two optional arguments:

- `path`: pathname where the ordinal number is to be stored (defaults to `order`)
- `scope`: pathname or array of pathnames relative to which numbers should be given (defaults to [])

*Example.* Chapters should not be numbered globally, but relative to the book to which they belong:

```
ChapterSchema.plugin(orderPlugin, { path: 'chapterNumber', scope: 'book' })
```

File `orderPlugin.js`:

```
function getConditions(doc, scope) {
  return Object.fromEntries([].concat(scope).map((path) => [path, doc[path]]))
}

export default (schema, options) => {
  const path = (options && options.path) || 'order'
  const scope = (options && options.scope) || {}

  schema.add({
    [path]: Number,
  })

  schema.pre('save', async function () {
    if (!this[path]) {
      const last = await this.constructor
        .findOne(getConditions(this, scope))
        .sort({ [path]: -1 })
      this[path] = last ? last[path] + 1 : 0
    }
  })

  schema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function (doc) {
    await this.model.updateMany(
      { [path]: { $gt: doc[path] }, ...getConditions(doc, scope) },
      { $inc: { [path]: -1 } }
    )
  })
}
```